# Is there a way to bind to the UIElement children in an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have a simple ItemsControl, bound to a list of simple data objects:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding dataModelCollection}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The children for the ItemsControl here, are the items in dataModelCollection, and these are simple model types. The Items control, however, will fill itself out with a bunch of Rectangles. Is there a way to bind to these rectangles, and not the data objects?

My assumption is that I can, since when an ItemsControl uses ItemsSource, it locks the Items property from being interfered with - you can't add other elements outside the ItemsSource. However, I have been searching for such a way, and have found nothing.

**EDIT:** This might look like a silly question, but the reason I am looking for an answer on this, is because I would like to use the ItemsControl to generate some UIElements for each item in dataModelCollection, and then put them on a Panel; I can't put them in the Panel directly, and I can't define the Panel as the ItemsControl.ItemsPanel because I need a reference to the actual Panel for some code-behind purposes.

Please keep my reasons mentioned above in mind when reading my following example of my desired outcome:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name=elementWrapper ItemsSource="{Binding dataModelCollection}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
<CustomControls:SpecialPanel x:Name="desiredHome" Elements="{Binding ElementName=elementWrapper, Path=ItemContainerGenerator.Items}" />
```

Comment: Why would you bind to the rectangles??? Can you show a bit of non-working code that you *want* to use or otherwise clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I went ahead and elaborated above.

Comment: That just sounds *weird*. I honestly don't know what if anything you can do. I just derived my own class off `ItemsControl` to do something similar, but I'm not sure that would work for you

Comment: You can't reuse the Rectangles that way, as they are already part of the ItemsControl's visual tree. They can't be in *another* visual tree at the same time. You might perhaps derive a specialized ItemsControl instead, and manipulate item containers in an overridden GetContainerForItemOverride method.

Comment: Can you just stick another itemscontrol in your panel with the same itemssource binding?

Comment: @Clemens, a fair point. I will likely need to think of a better way to frame my problem, in order to get what I want.